# How do I make all files/folders in/under usr folder permanently visible in Finder?

Tags: unix, osx-lion, finder

How do I make all files/folders in/under `usr` folder permanently visible in Finder?

I know how to temporarily make the these folders visible from:

"Search" in Finder; type "usr"; select "Other" from menu "Kind"; type "invisible"; select "File Visiblity"; select "Invisible Items" from menu... But I really don't want to do that every time I am looking for a file in the `usr`-tree.

I have also tried to the following code in the terminal:

```
$defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles True
$killall Finder
```

Not only does this make **all** files visible, but I can't seem to be able to find the `usr` folder.

Does anyone know how I make *only* the `usr`-tree permanently visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must have access to `/usr` from the finder, probably the easiest way is to create a symbolic link to it.  From a terminal session shell and using `usrlink` as an "alias":

```
sudo ln -s /usr /usrlink
sudo chmod -h 755 /usrlink
```

Then you should be able to see see the directories under `/usr` (which is filtered by the Finder) under `/usrlink` (which is not).  But I really don't recommend doing this.  It's too easy to mess `/usr` up inadvertently and, if you do, you're probably going to have to reinstall OS X.  Also, `.` files will still be hidden without changing other preferences.

Comment: I am definitively discourage, in every possible sense, by your reply. Does this also mean that it is more or less impossible to solve this problem in simple manner?

Comment: Apple hides `/usr` in the Finder for a good reason.  The Finder interface was never really intended to deal with the system-only files found there.  And you normally should never be modifying anything there anyway, other than possibly under `/usr/local`.  Your best bet is to use a conventional Unix shell in a Terminal session to view `/usr`.

Comment: My reason is that I need to link `h` files and library files to Xcode. I just found it highly annoying to go through my above mentioned cumbersome variant to make these folders temporarily visible. Besides, you need ROOT privileges to change anything outside `/usr/local/`, right? Still, all the folders/files I need access to are located under `/usr/local/`, so the question could just as well been: How do I make the `/usr/local/`-tree permanently visible?